# SUMO : How A Star algorithm heuristic is applied?

Tags: shortest-path, a-star, sumo

I'm using SUMO 0.30.0 and trying to simulate a graph (screenshot is attached below) as road network, and apply a star to find shortest path but not getting how heuristic function will work / applied.

I can consider graph nodes as road network junctions, edges as roads and edge weight as road length. But how to set heuristic value at junctions?

How I can assure if a single vehicle will start from junction A to junction Z using mentioned weights then it'll take the shortest path as A > C > D > E > Z

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUMO has the heuristic function already implemented, it is nothing the user can influence without modifying the code. It uses travel time (not road length) as the primary measurement and the lower bound is the air line distance between the two points in question divided by the maximum achievable speed in the network (which may depend on the maximum speed and/or the speed factor of the vehicle). Doesn't SUMO find the correct solution in your example?

Comment: Can you please share the documentation link? I'll share the result once it is done.

Comment: There is not so much documentation, I found only this http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Simulation/Routing#Routing_Algorithms